# Post app icon through facebook feed dialogue on fb wall

Tags: android, facebook

I am using [facebook feed dialogue](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/) to post on fb wall.
For this i am using the following bundle.

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", appName);
    params.putString("caption", "Any Caption");
    params.putString("description", "Any description");
    params.putString("link", "Any link);// App Link
    params.putString("picture", link);//Pic Link
```

Now I need to pass an app icon which selected from my custom listview instead of above "picture". How can I do this? Any help...

Answer (score 0):

The "picture" value must be an URL. So if you have the corresponding icons on the web somewhere, you can link to those instead. If you're dynamically generating the icons, then no, you can't do it.